# Escape a news listing page while crawling a news website with Scrapy

Tags: python-2.7, scrapy, web-crawler

I have to crawl articles from news websites, with certain keywords, I am using Scrapy for this task, for checking whether a keyword exist on a page or I extract the content from the page and search for the keyword. But I am facing the problem when there is listing page which has just listing of the news with links to the news page  e.g. [http://www.thehindu.com](http://www.thehindu.com/features/cinema/)/features/cinema/ , I want to escape this page, but I am unable to find a way to check whether it's is a listing page or not.

Comment: You need to add more details in order to get attention. And welcome to SO

Comment: Maybe you want to use different callbacks for the listing pages and for the news pages?

Comment: Thank you @Mr.777. What I am looking for is some type of implemented algorithm which can suggest whether the particular web page is just a listing page providing link to other pages or actually an article page.

Answer (score 0):

There are several methods to make this function.

You can use regular expression to filter the listing page url in the parse function of spider;

```
def parse(self, response):
    list_page_pat = re.compile("your pattern")
    for url in extract_urls:
        if list_page_pat.match(url) is None:
           //continue process
```

Comment: I require a generalized way to avoid listing pages because they contain no articles but just links to the news articles.
In your method, it requires the pattern explicitly but the problem here is the pattern is not known.
What I am lookink for is some algorithm which could identify whether it's a lising page or an article page.